# Error starting mysql service

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm having trouble on starting MariaDB instance. Here is the error I got: https://pastebin.com/RsdMxYRY. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Was this of any help:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html

Comment: @RickJames unfortunately not.

Comment: Did http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html help at all? What does your config files look like? Is this a fresh installation? Or a MariaDB that has been running for some time? Have you recently upgraded? Which OS and version is this running on? Have you recently changed any settings? How much memory is available to it? Is it on a dedicated server? Or do you have other software running there as well, such as a web server?